# Error when trying to create an envelope using Microsoft Flow - probably a timeout

Tags: docusignapi

We've been creating DocuSign envelopes via Microsoft Flow using the REST API. Today, we started to get an error "Http request failed: the timeout was reached.". Microsoft Flow retried 4 times, but with the same response. The timeout seems to be 2 minutes.

Looking at the DocuSign logs, it looks like it only received some of the first file before timing out. The BadRequest log indicates that the body is improperly formatted. I can see that only some of the Base64 encoding of the first document appears in the log.

I then tried submitting the same data via Postman. It succeeded within 57 seconds. Is there any reason why a submission from Microsoft Flow (or some other system) would be so much slower?

Request:

- URI: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxxx/envelopes
- Method: POST
- X-Docusign-Authentication: (username, password, integrator key)
- Content-Type: application/json
- Body:

```
{
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "538",
            "name": "My Document Name",
            "fileExtension": ".docx",
            "documentBase64": "xxxxx",
            "transformPdfFields": true
        },
        {
            "documentId": "537",
            "name": "Another Document",
            "fileExtension": ".docx",
            "documentBase64": "xxxx",
            "transformPdfFields": true
        }
    ],
    "status": "Sent",
    "emailSubject": "xxxx",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "recipientId": "1",
                "clientUserId": "1002457",
                "email": "lmckenzie@petstock.com.au",
                "name": " Ford",
                ".5routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {...
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "eventNotification": {
        "includeDocumentFields": "false",
        "envelopeEvents": [
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided"
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://xxx",
        "requireAcknowledgment": "false",
        "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
        "loggingEnabled": "true",
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "signMessageWithX509Cert": "true"
    }
}
```

Response:

`Duration: 2m
Start time: 2018-05-23T05:01:02.2710043Z
End time: 2018-05-23T05:03:02.384625Z
Status: BadRequest
Client request ID: c3cef685-7c70-41d0-8cbd-67237b56a7f1
Error: {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Http request failed: the timeout was reached."
    }
}`

Comment: Can you share the exact API req/resp which is failing, edit this qs with the req/resp

Comment: Updated question with Request and Response. I reran the same operation today and it completed without timing out. Is there a safer way of creating an envelope that is less likely to timeout?

Comment: Yes, use a transactionID, if you issue create envelope again within 7 days using same transactionID (this is an Async transaction), it will do one of the following: A. If the previous attempt was successful, it will NOT recreate the envelope and bring back current EnvelopeID and status. B. If the previous attempt was NOT successful, it will try again. I will say you see this behaviour in highly controlled QOS and packet inspection appliance based environments

Comment: Also, transactionID / Async envelope creation works best when coupled with Connect and "acid" logic to make sure what you want created, gets created. Of course this requires a database and related logic and envelope event model tracking for the complete envelope lifecycle.

Comment: Can you please share whats the total document size for documentId 538 and 537, and what could be the maximum size of document which you have plans to add in an envelope. Currently DocuSign supports at the max 25 MB document, also there is a 25 MB payload size limit also in one JSON request.

Comment: @Ivan how big of a document are you using and is it the same document you're sending in all the requests?  One possible reason why the same request might fail then work later is if due to the document size... you are base64 encoding it which bloats the document, then our platform encrypts the doc so that makes it even bigger.  I believe the hard limit on envelopes is 50MB but we generally recommend not sending larger than 25MB due to the size bloating etc.

Comment: The total size of the message, including all documents is 12 MB. This is after base64 encoding. The size of the individual documents in the envelope are all less than 3 MB. My test has been with the same set of documents, so no change in envelope size between tests.

Comment: A Suggestion - Do not use `"transformPdfFields": true` with docx, this attribute is only for Form Filled PDFs, 12 MB payload is not big. have you captured the payload and its size from DocuSign API logging? Also are you using Anchor Tags?